# How to align a list according to items in a reference list

Tags: python

I want to align listB according to the items in listA.

listA=`[('how', 0), ('to', 1), ('align', 2), ('a', 3), ('list', 4), ('according', 5), ('to', 6), ('a', 7), ('reference', 8), ('list', 9)]`

listB=`[('according', 0), ('to', 1), ('a', 2), ('reference', 3), ('list', 4), ('how', 5), ('to', 6), ('align', 7), ('a', 8), ('list', 9)]`

Desired output:

```
[('how', 5), ('to', 1), ('align', 7), ('a', 2), ('list', 4), ('according', 0), ('to', 6), ('a', 8), ('reference', 3), ('list', 9)]
```

Attempt:`sum([[y for y in listB if x[0]==y[0]] for x in listA],[])`

output from attempt:`[('how', 5), ('to', 1), ('to', 6), ('align', 7), ('a', 2), ('a', 8), ('list', 4), ('list', 9), ('according', 0), ('to', 1), ('to', 6), ('a', 2), ('a', 8), ('reference', 3), ('list', 4), ('list', 9)]`

The issue is every new search begins from the first item in listB.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, thanks. I want the items in listb to be arranged in the same way as the items in lista, just as what you see in the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two sequences contain (key, value) pairs. And you want to reorder (say "align") the second sequence  *listB* according to the keys of the sequence *listA*.

Notice: since the list of keys contains duplicates, you can not (easily) use `list.sort` function to reorder the second sequence. You need to write your own specific function.

Here is how I would achieve that:

```
def align(seq, ref_seq):
    '''align the sequence *seq* according to the keys in the reference sequence *ref_seq*'''
    seq = list(seq)  # local copy
    keys = [item[0] for item in seq]
    result = []
    for item_ref in ref_seq:
        key_ref = item_ref[0]
        if key_ref in keys:
            index = keys.index(key_ref)
            keys.pop(index)
            result.append(seq.pop(index))
    # keep what's left
    result.extend(seq)
    return result
```

You can use it like this:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(align(listB, listA))
```

You get:

```
[('how', 5),
 ('to', 1),
 ('align', 7),
 ('a', 2),
 ('list', 4),
 ('according', 0),
 ('to', 6),
 ('a', 8),
 ('reference', 3),
 ('list', 9)]
```

Comment: @Laurent_LAPORTE, thanks for the solution, it works.